# Lightweight method of decoding base16 (hexadecimals) of mixed case

Tags: java, guava

Guava has interface that allows for [base16/hexadecimal](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#base16%28%29) encoding and decoding. Is there a lightweight method or trick for reading in hexadecimals that may contain mixed case?

With lightweight I mean:

- no copying of the input string (so no `toUpperCase()` allowed)
- few lines of code
- low amount of additional instructions (performant)

The solution should not require an additional library on top of Java SE, and should be able to return relatively large byte arrays.

Code sample:

```
byte[] decoded = BaseEncoding.base16().decode("abCD");
```

will result in:

> com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: a

using Guava version 15.0 (the latest release at the time of this question).

Comment: It looks like the class you mention already does that. Have you tried it?

Comment: Where would you actually get mixed case hexadecimal in reality?  What encoders would ever write out mixed case hex?

Comment: @LouisWasserman As input from a user (including copy/paste). But an answer that just considers that a string could either contain one or the other would be fine as well. Obviously, it may be tricky to find out which one of the encodings is applicable without scanning the whole string.

Comment: @EJP I'll add a code sample right now, I did try it of course, but the class (and the RFC it points to) are rather strict. Which is OK for the other encodings maybe.

Comment: Do you have any actual evidence indicating that `toUpperCase` would actually be a performance bottleneck in your application, or that the allocation would be unacceptable?  Allocation, especially of short-lived objects, is cheaper than you might think.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't mind short lived objects, but I do mind data duplication in memory where it is not required. It's not a huge problem, I've got a very fast hex decoder myself (faster than any C# or Java version over here), but Guava seems a very useful library - except for the hex decoder it seems. I'm thinking of using substring and toUpperCase() for larger arrays, but that would require a new method - I may as well program it myself again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Apache commons-codec `Hex` class contains the methods you want. The actual code for converting chars to digits is:

```
protected static int toDigit(final char ch, final int index) throws DecoderException {
    final int digit = Character.digit(ch, 16);
    if (digit == -1) {
        throw new DecoderException("Illegal hexadecimal character " + ch + " at index " + index);
    }
    return digit;
}
```

And the property `Character.digit('F', 16) == Character.digit('f', 16)` holds.

Comment: So it’s just a wrapper around `java.lang.Character.digit(char, 16)`…

Comment: Yes, and bouncy has a Hexadecimal decoder as well, but I was not looking for alternatives here.

Comment: @Holger, and what isn't? (I actually upvoted your answer because non-3rd-party library looks better to me, and I totally forgot about `Integer.parseInt()`. The single difference that seems significant to me is that while `Hex` methods decode strings of arbitrary lengths, "corresponding" `Integer` or `Long` methods can only deal with strings representing numbers which fit their types' bounds, so it's still worth mentioning - just in case.)

Comment: I've marked this as accepted asnwer - as long as there is no good alternative in normal Java / Guava in an answer it's probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer.parseInt(string, 16);` does exactly what you describe. If that’s too easy for you, you may look into its implementation to learn how to do such a thing. But it’s more than a few lines as it will handle all corner cases you might forget when doing it yourself. E.g. the allowed maximum absolute value differs for positive and negative values. The only difference between an optimized hexadecimal and an arbitrary radix parsing is that you can use `result<<=4;` instead of `result *= radix;` for the hexadecimal case.

---

Given your updated question the recommendation to look into that method still applies. Decoding a sequence of bytes instead of an `int` will be even simpler:

```
import static java.lang.Character.digit;
…

static byte[] decode(CharSequence cs)
{
  final int numCh = cs.length();
  if((numCh&1)!=0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("cs must have an even length");
  byte[] array=new byte[numCh>>1];
  for(int p=0; p<numCh; p+=2)
  {
    int hi=digit(cs.charAt(p), 16), lo=digit(cs.charAt(p+1), 16);
    if((hi|lo)<0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(cs+" contains non-hex characters");
    array[p>>1]=(byte)(hi<<4|lo);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I was trying to convert from string to byte array as Guava does. I've added that constraint - which I thought should be intrinsic to the question - to the question.

Comment: So converting `int`s to a byte array is hard to you? Do you know about `ByteBuffer.putInt`? So you downvote because *you* were unable to ask the right question?

Comment: I'm not looking for alternate implementations (and I'm not sure you test the hex digits enough). I need a library I can show my fellow developers and say: you can use this for encoding/decoding to hex & base64. Without each and every one of them running into this issue. For now I'll just recommend `toUpperCase()` and a separate library for larger swats of hex I guess.

Comment: The method `java.lang.Character.digit` is tested well enough to leave no doubt. Man, if you need a library you can show your “fellow developers” then put that method into a library and show that library to your “fellow developers”… This is first-grade programming. If you need a third party library for every trivial line of code you should stop programming and change your job. Or just stay at `String.toUpperCase`; this works well enough for you as you don’t seem to be the man who should think about performance. Adding another third party library creates more overhead than `String.toUpperCase`.

Comment: I'll keep it at `toUpperCase()`, making a note that this is not memory optimal. Please don't insult me just for hinting that this does not directly answer my question. There are many hex decoders here in the company, most of them created on the fly. About 50% has some kind of error or inconsistency. I must admit though that the code above does check for illegal digits (by using the -1 value returned by the `digit()` method).